# Maya Calendar Uninstall

Tags: calendar

Don't know how to uninstall Maya Calendar? It doesn't show up in the software center if I search. Only thing that pops up under installed is Evolution Data Server which I uninstalled but still maya calendar is available under applications.
Any Suggestions?
(Am not happy with Geary and Maya since I need integration between my mail client and my calendar, most important I need be able to create events out of a mail. Best would be with date recognition and that the event refers back to the mail - Mac Os x features, which where important parts of my work-flow on my hackintosh. Would love to stick with elementary, but this is really missing. Will try now with thunderbird)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open terminal and run the following commands:

- To uninstall `maya-calendar`

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove maya-calendar
  ```
- To uninstall `maya-calender and dependencies:

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove maya-calendar
  ```
- Purge your config/data too:

  ```
  sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove maya-calendar
  ```

**Caution! Purged config/data can not be restored by reinstalling the package**

Comment: Dank allen hier für die Hilfe.

Comment: Dank allen hier für die Hilfe. Ravan, Dein Kommentar ist insbesondere schön übersichtlich. Kann ich so eigentlich mit allen Programmen umgehen. Auch Programmen die ich über shell script (.sn) oder wie das auch immer heißt installiert habe. Habe nämlich oft das Problem, dass ich bei der Installation irgendwelche Optionen falsch ausgewählt habe, die ich im Nachhinein nicht zu ändern weiß. Dann will ich das Programm einfach neu installieren, aber der erneute Installationsprozess überspringt diese Optionen, da er wahrscheinlich die alten config/data erkennt...?

Comment: Sorry am German, sometimes I don't realize, which Language I use. Now in English. Thanks to everyone. Ravan, specially your comment gives a beautiful overview. Can I aply that method for all Programs as well for programs I have installed with shell scripts (.sn) or however you call that...? Often I have the Problem, that whaile installing I choose some wrong options, which I don't know how to change them later. So I decide to just reinstall, but while reinstalling these options don't pop up again, asume, cause the Installer recognizes the old config/data...?

Comment: Sorry not .sn but .sh...

Comment: @Florian As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text,Also ,these are standard (AFAIK) for manually installed applications. thank you=)

Comment: Ah confusing, tried to click the arrow up, and mashine told me I can't do that, but I can click the tick... so i know now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

run this in terminal

`sudo apt-get purge maya-calendar && sudo apt-get autoremove`

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get purge maya-calendar` will remove the application, while `sudo apt-get autoremove` will remove the package's dependencies.

As for the mail client, I don't really have any advice. I just use my browser.